# Installing Ghostscript and Convert-IM along with MacTex

Tags: installing, mactex, ghostscript

Do someone of you know if the installation of Ghostscript and Convert-IM packages which come along with MacTex is mandatory? Are these packages useful or I can proceed without install them?

Comment: If you don't plan ever using EPS files, then Ghostscript is not necessary; which means it's recommended. Also ImageMagick is handy at times. I'd install both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing Ghostscript is not mandatory, but many auxiliary programs require it when managing EPS files. So, if you plan never using EPS files, then you can avoid installing Ghostscript; but, as EPS files are ubiquitous, I don't see any real reason for saving a tiny bit of space.

ImageMagick, on the other hand, is a collection of utilities for dealing with graphic formats. I surely would install it; it's used by the `standalone` class, that is so able to automatically convert the PDF output into other graphic formats.

Answer (score 0):

Their installations are not mandatory, though both of them are very useful, as egreg explained.

There is a custom install option in the MacTeX installer package, and if you click on this option you may choose not to install Ghostscript nor Convert (which is only a subpart of ImageMagick by the way).